# How can I edit a command?

Tags: command-line, scripts, alias, binary

I'm trying to edit the clear command. I've tried going into the bin directory then doing: "gedit clear" but it ended in failure because I can't edit the file without potentially corrupting it.

I'm trying to make the 'clear' command clear the screen, and then make some ASCII art after it clears. I've been able to do it, but only with functions I made in `.bashrc`. I want to make it do the same thing but without using a different name. I want to be able to type the default `clear` and it will do the thing I made.

Sorry if there is something I'm missing. I'm a noob.

Comment: As "a n00b", I am curious as to why you are trying to edit core Linux tools. If there is something specific that you would like to do, perhaps a shell script with a convenient alias would suffice? This would certainly get around the problem of future updates overwriting your changes. Could you explain what it is that you're trying to accomplish? Someone may be able to offer a better solution for you 

Comment: If you are at the command line the command `history` will show you all your recent commands. Scroll to the command you want, copy paste it in the command line and edit it using the left and right arrow keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you already have a script somewhere that draws defined or random ASCII art for you. Let's say this script is located here: `/usr/local/bin/ascii_art.sh`, and is set to be executable.

Then you create an `alias` (in either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` - your preference):

```
alias clear='\clear; /usr/local/bin/ascii_art.sh'
```

Now, when you run the `clear` command, it first executes the default binary `clear`, and just afterwards executes your script with ASCII art.

You could also make things even easier for yourself, by making a shorter `alias`, like `cl`.

Or you could make a keybinding (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) to run your alias - add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind -x '"\C-b": clear'
```

Comment: thank you. this is exactly what i needed! i wish i could do a positive vote but it says i need 15 reputation :(

Comment: No worries - good to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to edit a command you need to find the source code, alter it and then compile it.

Generally I would 1st explore the option to create a new script (or even a function) that does what you want to do. And if it does what you want put this new script in a directory preseeding the one that holds clear.

```
$ which clear
/usr/bin/clear

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

... so for instance `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit a binary file, you should instead edit [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html)'s (`clear` is part of the ncurses package) source code and then compile and install it (see INSTALL file in ncurses source code). Alternatively, write your own with shell script/use aliases if you need to add extra commands before/after running clear.